# The INSERT statement conflicted with the CHECK constraint.conflict occurred in database

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

The solution for above subject line exists in many links and have come across all links and find no solution for my issue.

here is my query :

```
 INSERT INTO PatientPatternElements (PatientPatternsID, ASEventID, LocationID, EffectiveDate, EffectiveDateEnd, WorkloadStartDate, WorkloadEndDate)
                SELECT DISTINCT PatientPatterns.ID, 
                        @hl7event_id, 
                        @default_locationid,
                        @hl7event_effective_date, 
                        @hl7event_effective_date, 
                        @hl7event_effective_date, 
                        @hl7event_effective_date 
                FROM PatientPatternElements
                INNER JOIN PatientPatterns
                    ON PatientPatternElements.PatientPatternsID = PatientPatterns.ID
                WHERE PatientPatterns.PatientEncounterID = @patient_encounter_id
                    AND PatientPatterns.Visit = @patient_encounter_visit

                ---------------------
                -- Error Checking
                ----------------------
                SET @SysError =  @@error
                IF @SysError != 0
                BEGIN
                    SET @iError = 23063
                    SET @strErrorMsg = 'Error Applying Manual Discharge Event, Error: ' + cast(@SysError AS varchar(256)) + ' encounter_id=' + cast(@patient_encounter_id as varchar(64))
                    GOTO ERROR 
                END
```

It is  just a part of my code of my stored procedure.

**WORKFLOW**

It is happening in one of the version in client testing environment and client has one more version and the flow works without any issues.
when we are trying to run a record manually it is throwing an error in one of our log table and throws below message:

```
THREAD 4: ApplyPatientPatternEvents: Recovering from SQL exception: The INSERT statement conflicted with the CHECK constraint "CK_PatientPatternElements_Location". 
The conflict occurred in database "db_name", table "dbo.PatPatternElements".
```

and this

```
Rolling back Transaction. spHL7ApplyPatientPatternEvents: Error Applying Manual Discharge Event, Error: 547 encounter_id=20
```

as I said earlier it is happening in only one version, stored procedure is identical in both the versions, making hard to find out the issue.

there is nothing logged in Eventviewer and tracing sql profiler also not helping much since the SP `spHL7ApplyPatientPatternEvents` never show up in profiler.

Anyone can give an idea what exactly has happened ?

This is the query of constraint.

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[PatientPatternElements]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [CK_PatientPatternElements_Location] CHECK  (([LocationID] IS NULL AND [LevelOfCareGroupID] IS NOT NULL OR [LocationID] IS NOT NULL AND [LevelOfCareGroupID] IS NULL))
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[PatientPatternElements] CHECK CONSTRAINT     [CK_PatientPatternElements_Location]
GO
```

Comment: Can you supply parameter values that raise the error?

Comment: Those parameters are used in many places hence making hard to trace the value, do you have any better idea to find the values of those parameters ?

Comment: Sorry, I thought `when we are trying to run a record manually it is throwing an error` meant you recreate the error.  Once method is to wrap the insert statement in a [try...catch block](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms175976.aspx).  Use the catch block to divert parameter values, [user](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187934.aspx) and [host](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178598.aspx) names to your log table.

Comment: Added Try to insert query and Catch to error. but what will this give us ?

Comment: It gives you the ability to track where, when, what and who is causing the error. Armed with this information you should be able to fix.

Answer (score 0):

Manjuboyz,

The following points may help you to understand what is happening in the code.

1. As you have mentioned "there are two environments. And the Insert statement is working fine in one environment and not in the other". Based on this statement, Can I suggest you to check if the same constraint is present in both the environments.
2. CHECK constraint here is checking whether the values getting inserted have the specified value. If it fails then the constraint will fail with the error you mentioned. So please do the exception handling with TRY, CATCH placing the insert statement under TRY. So if there is any error in the CATCH block you can capture the error, and also the values of [LocationID] and [LevelOfCareGroupID] getting inserted.
3. `ALTER TABLE [dbo].[PatientPatternElements]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [CK_PatientPatternElements_Location] CHECK  (([LocationID] IS NULL AND [LevelOfCareGroupID] IS NOT NULL OR [LocationID] IS NOT NULL AND [LevelOfCareGroupID] IS NULL))
   GO`

Based on the above CHECK constraint you have provided we can understand that, the insert statement will work ONLY WHEN "ANY ONE OF those paramters" i.e. **[LocationID]** or **[LevelOfCareGroupID]** is NULL. but not **BOTH**.

i.e.  if  [LocationID] is NULL, and [LevelOfCareGroupID] is NULL. then INSERT will **FAIL**

similarly, if  [LocationID] is NOT NULL, and [LevelOfCareGroupID] is NOT NULL. then also INSERT will **FAIL**